# iOS app keep increasing the memory?(Memory Crash) DidReceiveMemoryWarning

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have developed the app which using `MKMapView,MoviePlayer,Recording Videos,Downloading the Videos and Uploading videos at Amazone Server`.

Now when i just open the screen with `MKMapview` window its just increased the memory to 10 MB every time and when i back from that screen it decrease only 5 MB. same with `MPMoviePlayer`.

My Uploading thread is running continuously in background mode.(it will check for some plist file and if plist file have some entries it will start uploading the videos in background process and after completing it will stop the thread for 1 minute and then again start it for foresaid process) but i kept the object with the __weak Property so thats not the reason which using my memory.

i have doubt in **MKMapview and MPMoviewPlayer** for using high memory and not realocating it.

in my application i have videos to be played from server and while playing it i need to download the same videos from the server.

mean while user can also see the map.

Now my problem is may be my application is using so much things so while running it memory reaches to **218 MB** and crashes the app if i use it continuously and accessing it very roughly.

so can anyone suggest me what can i do to prevent this out of memory crash.?i have also check the memory leaks.but i dint found that much important leaks yet.

What i thinking is the `UIImagePickerController,MkMapview,MPMoviewplayer,Download,upload Videos` this kind of functionality making my app eating more memories.
phone memory just keep on going high and high as i visit screen in my applications...

Comment: Use Instruments and see what is using the memory. You may have a few reference cycles keeping objects from being deallocated.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I would check is if you are creating a lot of autorelease objects, and do not drain the autorelease pool. If you do not set up your own autorelease pools using `@autoreleasepool {...}`, the default autorelease pool will only be emptied when the app comes back to the main event loop. Also, any background thread should have an autorelease pool installed. Please look up [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html).

Comment: i have ARC enabled in my project

Comment: @BhavikKama: ARC doesn't mean you don't have to think about memory consumption!

Comment: so i need to use @autoreleasepool {...} in background thread or in each methods which using more memories?

Comment: The docs say "If your application or thread is long-lived and potentially generates a lot of autoreleased objects, you should use autorelease pool blocks ...; otherwise, autoreleased objects accumulate and your memory footprint grows." This is independent of ARC or not. Autorelease objects are created in very many cases, e.g. by using [NSArray array] or by using a getter. If you do this very often in a loop, it might make sense to setup an autorelease pool just for the loop body.